# Regex for including alphanumeric and special characters but not special characters on their own

Tags: c#, regex, fluentvalidation

Im trying to create some validation rules for a data member, but am having trouble with one of my regular expressions. Currently I am using `@"[a-zA-Z']+$"` as I want to allow strings such as:

- John Smith (valid)
- Steve Mc'millan (valid)
- ''''' (invalid)
- Hill St' (valid)

This works as expected, but when I try pass a string with just the special characters, it allows it. Is there a way where I can allow the special characters `'`, but not allow it on its own?

Here is my rule Im creating:

```
        RuleFor(h => h.Name)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is required")
            .Matches(@"[a-zA-Z']+$").WithMessage("{PropertyName} is invalid");
```

Comment: Would you always have the Uppercase char followed by a single lowercase and then the single quote? If so, try: [`^[A-Z][a-z]'?[a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]'?[a-z]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/xVivAu/1)

Comment: You can probably use `@"^(?!'$)[a-zA-Z']+$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
RuleFor(h => h.Name)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is required")
    .Matches(@"^(?!'+$)[a-zA-Z']+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z']+)*$").WithMessage("{PropertyName} is invalid");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2kx77/1/).

- `^` - matches the start of string position
- `(?!'+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more `'` chars followed by the end of string position immediately to the right of the current (i.e. start of string) position.
- `[a-zA-Z']+` - one or more letters or `'`
- `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z']+)*`  - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z']+` - one or more letters or `'` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: How can I make it stop if the value is more than just one `'`? It works with 1, but if the value is `''` or more, it allows it

Comment: It almost works, but does not allow a space after the `'`, for things like `St' Hellens`